# Using Bayes approach for hypothesis testing

Tags: bayesian, hypothesis-testing

I was given this question in an interview. I solved the first part using a frequentist approach. But there was no time for second part (using Bayesian).

Let's say we are given two jars with an infinite number of red and blue marbles in each one. We want to test whether the fraction of the number of red marbles in both jars is the same.

To do this, I can set up a hypothesis test. The null hypothesis is p1 = p2 where p1 is the fraction of red marbles in jar A and p2 the fraction of red marbles in jar B.

Now, let's say I'm given prior knowledge that there are 2/3 red marbles in jar A and 1/2 red marbles in jar B. How this change the problem? How can I use Bayes in this situation?

Comment: If you're given prior knowledge that the fraction of red marbles is different, then the fraction of red marbles is different, and drawing from the jars doesn't affect this. Although it's a bit unclear what it means to say that half the marbles in a jar with infinitely many marbles in it are red; this doesn't obviously make sense if there are countably many marbles.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : Taken literally, your comment about what doesn't make sense with infinitely many marbles makes sense, but I don't think it was intended literally. That $2/3$ of the marbles in a jar are red would just mean that's your probability of getting a red marble, and it remains $2/3$ even if you don't put it back. But certainly that could have been said more clearly.